# How to add maven dependencies of json to modules in >= Java 9

Tags: java, json, maven, java-platform-module-system, module-info

in java 8 projects you simply add the following dependencys in maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Using OpenJDK, Eclipse 2018-12
and maven module, it results in getting a error in the module-info.java:

> The package javax.json.stream is accessible from more than one module:
>   java.json, org.glassfish.java.json

So in both dependency projects there is a package called javax.json.stream and due to jigsaw module system this is not allowed anymore?

How to fix this?

**EDIT:**
I updated the maven dependency to 1.1.4 and put them on the classpath.
The `javax.json-api` has a module-info.java file and is working fine, eclipse shows no more errors.
But now the packages of the implementation `javax.json (org.glassfish)` are not found, resulting in a `ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl`
What more can I do?

**EDIT:**
Its working now, i forgot to generate a module-info.java in this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So in both dependency projects there is a package called
>   javax.json.stream and due to jigsaw module system this is not allowed
>   anymore?

This is still allowed, **but** with both those dependencies getting resolved on the *classpath* instead of *modulepath* i.e. in the *unnamed module*.

Another alternative to fix this while you create your library as modular is to make sure to fix the downstream libraries exporting the same package which would require a bottom-up migration and you might have to wait for them to fix it in their latest update(or check if one is already out) and then to rely on them.

Comment: i put the maven dependencies on the classpath, but now the packages of org.glassfish are not found (the jar is present in the maven dependencies). How is this possible? (The javax.json-api-1.1.4 is already updated, and has a module-info.java file, everything is found and fine, but the javax.json-1.1.4.jar has not.)